# How to get the size of typed memoryviews in cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, memoryview

Is it possible to get the size of a MemoryView in cython? Ideally, I'm looking for something like `arr.shape` in numpy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview

> len(view) is equal to the length of tolist. If view.ndim = 0, the
>   length is 1. If view.ndim = 1, the length is equal to the number of
>   elements in the view. For higher dimensions, the length is equal to
>   the length of the nested list representation of the view. The itemsize
>   attribute will give you the number of bytes in a single element.